# Where is undefined method of `name` coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did a

```
rails g migration add_position_to_products position:integer
```

Let me explain the logic of what I am doing here. In order for my system to know what order to put the items in, I need a frame of reference, some attribute in the database that can be stored where I can say, you see this position right here, this number is the order that I want you to base the sort on.

Below I provide a bit of a visual:

[image]

So if I want to set the position number for these Radish shoots item to 5 then I would expect the radish shoots to be at position 5 in the images below so five block below where it is now. And so the way I want this system to work is when I click and drag the item and move it to a different position, what I want is for the system to go and dynamically change that position value.

So the rails migration above is me creating the element in the database for the position.

I did a

```
rails db:migrate
```

Then I needed to create a scope. I went to ProductsController and placed it in the index action:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  layout 'product'
  access all: [:show, :index], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit]}, site_admin: :all

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.order("position ASC")
    @products = Product.page(params[:page]).per(9)
    @page_title = "Products"
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @page_title = @product.summary
    @seo_keywords = @product.description
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:summary, :description, :image, :user)
    end
end
```

So what the above in the index action should do is look for the position attribute in the Products database table and order the elements starting at the lowest and going to the highest.

So far so good.

However, when I go into my Rails console, I go Product.last I get a nil position:

```
Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Product id: 6, summary: "one more", description: "one more product", image: "abstract-1851074_1280.jpg", created_at: "2017-09-12 19:59:13", updated_at: "2017-09-12 19:59:13", user_id: nil, active: nil, price: nil, position: nil>
```

When I do:

```
2.3.3 :002 > Product.last.update!(position: 1)
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Product:0x007ff4e7aa82a8>
```

And I do not know where that undefined method of `name` is because we had changed Product.summary to Product.name previously, but I found that it broke things. So I changed it back to Product.summary. So what undefined method of `name` is it referring to?

Here is the schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170915143515) do

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.float    "subtotal"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_carts_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_carts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "homes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "summary"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.float    "price"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "roles"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

This is the models/product.rb file:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user , presence: true
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories


 validates :summary, :price, presence: true

   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

end
```

In console I see that there is a user_id: and price: that is nil and that cannot be nil as you see above presence: true.

I did not develop out those features, looks like they were done after I developed the edit forms. At this point, I am not sure how to proceed here on Stack Overflow. The error/issue has changed now, please advise. I guess I could mark Jacobs answer as the correct one, since by mentioning Products model, it lead me to figure out why I was getting undefined method of name.

Comment: I don't see `Product#name` being used anywhere. Does this code raise that error now?

Comment: Have you done `reload!` in the console?

Comment: @RajMishra, even after I do a reload bang, I still get the error.

Comment: Can you post your Product model?

Comment: Please post your `Product` model and the full error message including file names, line numbers and the full stack trace.

Comment: @JacobVanus, when you mentioned the Product model I saw that it has a line of code of validates :name and when I changed it to :summary, I am getting a different error now. I am posting it above with the change I made.

Comment: @JacobVanus, can you post your reply as an answer, it did lead to correcting the issue.

Comment: I was going to recommend that you accept @JacobVanus answer as the correct one and then ask a new question. You not knowing this is probably why you got downvoted. Please review this link for more help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253098/what-is-the-best-thing-to-do-if-one-question-leads-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you post your Product model?

I'm glad my question led to you finding a solution! Just in case somebody comes across this page later, I'll attempt to sum up the solution which @Ale found for himself...

**origional product.rb:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user , presence: true
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories


 validates :name, :price, presence: true

   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

end
```

**updated product.rb:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user , presence: true
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories


 validates :summary, :price, presence: true

   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

end
```

Comment: @Ale, please let me know if I'm materially wrong about the original file contents and I'll update.